# VS Code Live Share Flutter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I have a flutter project and an android emulator running.

With visual studio code live share my friend can se all my files and code.

How can he run the code on an emulator on his end as well? 
Because now he can only see the code but can't run the app.

Is it possible for him to see my emulator or run the project himself?

Answer (score 1):

Vscode shares only the code.

If you want to share the app too, you'll need another program such as TeamViewer or similar.

Comment: While live sharing you can also share console and server. 
While coding a website for example my friend can have the website running against my local server asewell